# interacting with multi_line in bokeh

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, interactive, bokeh

Trying to plot 2 lines in Bokeh and update them simultaneously based on inputs from 2 sliders. When I use multi_line, the lines do not update.

Using ipython notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np    
from ipywidgets import interact

from bokeh.models import Line, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
```

Define 2 simple functions that give me my 2 lines over the same x-values:

```
def mu(q,tau,c):
    p = np.maximum((tau-2*q-c),0)
    return p*q

def mu_d(q,tau,c):
    mask = (tau-q-c)<0
    payoff = .25*(tau-q-c)**2
    payoff[mask]=0
    return payoff
```

Now make the Bokeh plot:

```
x = np.linspace(0, .6, 200)
y = mu(x,1,.1)
y1 = mu_d(x,1,.1)

output_notebook()

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, y1=y1))
p = figure(title="simple line example", plot_height=300, plot_width=600, y_range=(0, .25))
# p.line(x, y, source=source, alpha=.5, color="red", line_width=2) #this case works
# p.line(x, y1, source=source, alpha=.5, color="red", line_width=2) #this case does not
p.multi_line([x,x], [y,y1], source=source, alpha=.5, color=["red","blue"], line_width=2) # neither does this


def update(tau=1, c=.1):
    source.data['y'] = mu(x,tau,c)
    source.data['y1'] = mu_d(x,tau,c)
    source.push_notebook()

show(p)
```

And the slider:

```
interact(update,  tau=(0,1, 0.1), c=(0,.5, 0.1))
```

To debug things, I've been playing with plotting single lines. Things work fine if I plot only (x,y) as in the first case (commented out). When I try the second case, the line (x,y1) turns into (x,y) when the slider updates - even when I've restarted the kernel and commented out the unused `source.data` lines (bug?). I've printed the `mu_d()` output within the `update` command and things look nice there, but they don't update in the figure.

Anyone else encountered this? All tools (ipython, bokeh, etc.) are the latest version as in the Anaconda dist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't multi-line, but works. Would be nice if this could be vectorized, so that any number of lines could be manipulated at once without writing a ton of code.

```
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=qgrid, y=mugrid))
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=qgrid, y=mudgrid))

p.line(qgrid, mugrid, source=source1, legend='mu(q)',line_color="blue",alpha=.6)
p.line(qgrid, mudgrid,source=source2,legend='mu_d(q)',line_color="green",alpha=.5)

p.legend.label_text_font = "times"    

def update(tau=1, c=.1):
    source1.data['y'] = mu(x,tau,c)
    source2.data['y'] = mu_d(x,tau,c)
    source1.push_notebook()
    source2.push_notebook()

show(p)
```